# generate code via several yaml file using swagger codegen plugin

Tags: java, maven, swagger-codegen

I have several swagger yaml files and I want to generate code at compile time using maven.

here is my code:

```
 <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-codegen-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/*.yaml</inputSpec>
                        <language>java</language>
                        <configOptions>
                            <sourceFolder>src/gen/java/main</sourceFolder>
                        </configOptions>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

I'm trying to get all the yaml files I have in the resources as input :

```
<inputSpec>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/*.yaml</inputSpec>
```

but this do not work, I've got this error:

```
failed to read resource listing
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Projets\www\codegen\src\main\resources\*.yaml (La syntaxe du nom de fichier, de répertoire ou de volume est incorrecte)
```

Any Idea ?

Comment: Im fairly certain that swagger does not allow wildcards for `inputSpec` you must specify a single file at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was resolved by using multiple executions as follow :

```
         <plugin>
            <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-codegen-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.5</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>a</id> .....
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>b</id> .....
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>c</id> .....
                </execution>
             </executions>
          </plugin>
```

Comment: But each yaml file generates the same component classes if they are common in all swaggers, so then u have plenty of the same classes but in different packages.. Have you faced it ?

Comment: Yes sure! But still in the different packages so it s okay!

Comment: @michealAtmi you have to create a hierarchy of spec yaml files. the top level with specific stuff and you include the common parts. this way, you only generate one time. I did it with graddle and it worked fine.